# Node.js scheduling jobs with node-schedule not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

I'm trying to schedule a job for removing a certain document from my mongodb database, when I execute the job immediately after doing the request it works, but, upon requesting to remove the doc after 1 hour (for example), it does not remove from the database. Here's my code:

```
 app.delete('logauth/removecourse/:uuid/:hours', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
        if(req.user.usertype == 1)
        {
          Teacher.findOne({ _id : req.user.teacher }, function(err, teacher){
              if(err)
                res.send(err);

              var scheduled = schedule.scheduleJob(new Date(Date.now() + (req.params.hours * 3600000)), function(uuid, teach_id){
                return function(){
                  Course.find({ _id : uuid, teacher : teach_id }).remove().exec(function(err){
                    if(err)
                      res.send(err);
                    });
                  }
              }(req.params.uuid, teacher._id));

              if(scheduled)
                res.send(200); 
              else
                res.send(500); 
          });
        }
        else
        {
            res.send(403); 
        }
    });
```

Any tips as for what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is the way that you set the hours, check this:

```
app.delete('logauth/removecourse/:uuid/:hours', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    if(req.user.usertype == 1)
    {
      Teacher.findOne({ _id : req.user.teacher }, function(err, teacher){
          if(err)
            res.send(err);
              var d = new Date();
              d.setHours(d.getHours()+1, d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds());
          var scheduled = schedule.scheduleJob(d, function(uuid, teach_id){
            return function(){
              Course.find({ _id : uuid, teacher : teach_id }).remove().exec(function(err){
                if(err)
                  res.send(err);
                });
              }
          }(req.params.uuid, teacher._id));

          if(scheduled)
            res.send(200); 
          else
            res.send(500); 
      });
    }
    else
    {
        res.send(403); 
    }
});
```